# Image showing on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: html, image

I am accessing images that are on the same server but a sister website. So instead of accessing the image locally, I'm using the full root path to the sister website: https://example.com/images/img.jpg

Problem is that the images show up fine on the desktop but not on mobile (both Safari and Chrome). Is this some kind of security thing with mobile browsers? Is it possible to grab the image from the root path (/home/servernameexample/public_html/images/img.jpg didn't work)?

Comment: Please share the complete code of how you're including images. I fear you're trying to display images with a local path based on your own machine instead of a web address

Comment: background-image: url(https://example.com/images/blog/hero/1-4189.jpg); AND <img src="https://example.com/images/blog/article/1-7036.jpg">. Two different images. Sorry won't let me post https:// but it's there.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how you're including the images if the path is correct. So either there are some issues on the path, or the website you're including the images from limits access in some way

Comment: I think it's the second one but don't know what it might be or where to start looking.

Comment: Use chrome desktop, change the useragent to a mobile one, then inspect the network calls from the Chrome Developer tools to see exactly what fails

Comment: So I set user agent to Chrome - iPad but images are fine with no errors.

Comment: Maybe it's a connection problem? The second website can only be reached from your desktop connection because it's via hosts or it's hosted locally?

Comment: Via GoDaddy shared hosting

Comment: So this is weird - I open the page on my phone and the image is not there. But if I tap and hold to show the missing image in a new tab it's there. Going to do more tests.

Comment: Bizzare. Plain vanilla html page. Only code is: test<br>
  <img alt="test" src="https://piazzahospitality.com/images/blog/article/1-7036.jpg">. Works on desktop but not mobile.

Comment: Works perfectly from my mobile : https://imgur.com/a/RhaHwql The image is quite heavy, it's half a MB, so maybe it's too heave for your mobile to render within the HTML or too heavy to load or your mobile has some network limits to save bandwidth

Comment: Pretty sure not the file load. Smaller file, same results. If I load the same image on same domain, using full URL it works fine. Just won't work for images outside same domain - at least for me. Will run more tests. Thanks for trying to help.